# Constructors usage in Java for beginners

Tags: java, arrays, methods, constructor

**Target -**

try to create class with few functions - create array and do with it some operations
Now i want that user enter length of array and programm return it to user

**Whats done? -**

Created class:

```
public class Array {
    private int myArray[];
    private int count;

    Array(int length){
        myArray = new int[length];// create mas of diff length
        count =0 ; // count q-ty of elements
    }

    //array out
    public static void outArray(int array[]){
        int length = array.length;
        for (int i=0; i<length+1; i++){
            System.out.println("Element number ["+i+"] is ["+ array[i]+"]");
        }
    }
```

And main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("What length of your array? []");
    Array matrix = new Array(Array.getCharToInt());
    Array.outArray(matrix);
....
```

**Whats happend -**

Here i have some problem
    Array.outArray(matrix);

**Question -**

Where did I make a mistake? also try a lot of variant,but cant understand what i'm doing wrong.

---

Change function for taking Array instance, but now i have problem with method .. - cant get length of array`

```
Array(int length){
    myArray = new int[length];// create mas of diff length
    int myLength=myArray.length;
}

//array out
public static void outArray(Array array){
    int length = array.myLength; - cant do like this - "myLength cannot be resolved or is not a field".
```

I think if I add some fields to the constructor I can use it or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is exactly "some problem"?

Comment: Your `outArray` function does not take an `Array` instance, but an actual int array. Fix that up and you'll be ok.

Comment: It would also help to know what you *want* to do. "do with it some operations" is much too vague.

Comment: You also want to remove the `+1` after `i<length+1` because you would get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if you try to run the program.

Comment: Changed method - see ufter question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to define array is:

```
private int[] myArray;
```

So your constructor and class will be:

```
public class Array {
private int[] myArr;
private int count;

public Array(int length) {
    myArr = new int[length];
    count = 0;
}

public int[] getInnerArray() {
    return myArr;
}

public static void processArray(Array array) {
    int[] innerArray = array.getInnerArray();
    int length = innerArray.length;
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Next [" + i + "] is - " + innerArray[i]);
    }
}
```

But also u can change public static void processArray(Array array) method to the instance method:

```
 public void processArray() {
    int[] innerArray = myArr;
    int length = innerArray.length;
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Next [" + i + "] is - " + innerArray[i]);
    }
}
```

and main func will be:

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    System.out.println("What length of your array? []");
    Array matrix = new Array(666);
    matrix.processArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First I would recomend that you carefully read the posts from Perception, and Java. For your problem with "myLength cannot be resolved or is not a field", is because you are calling array.myLength. myLength is a variable that you created when the Array class is called. Keep in mind every time you call a new instance of a Class, that they will be seperate. If you want use different methods from in a Class, create an instance of that class in your main Project class, ie.. You are also using private variable declarations int the Array class that are never used.

Also there is allready a class named "Array" in java.lang.reflect.Array. If your trying to create your own class and not overriding methods in the class you may also want to consider renaming your Array class. Then do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
MyArrayClass mAC = new MyArrayClass;
System.out.println("What length of your array? []");
int[] matrix = new int[mAC.getCharToInt()];
mAC.outArray(matrix);
```

then change your outArray method to

```
public static void outArray(int array[]){
int length = array.length;
for (int i=0; i<length; i++){
System.out.println("Element number ["+i+"] is ["+ array[i]+"]");
}
```

I like to use private variables, you have attempted to use, however you also need to implement getter and setter methods for getting to the variable.